# Computers on network restarts with BSOD

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, bsod

I'm having one confusing problem.
In network I have 50+ PCs. Most of them are win7 / win 10, only few are still on windows xp sp2/sp3 ( Its still on xp, because they are some cnc machines for produciton).

This few on xp are randomly restarting with BSOD irql_not_less_or_equal.
When network cable is unpluged computers work all fine.

This problem showed up in last 10-15 days. Only change in network in last months was adding one wirelles router  ( Mi router 3 AC1200 )   - using as AccessPoint

I tryed:

-reinstaling network driver

-changing RAM

-adding aditional network card

-reconfiguring UPS

-changed 3 switches ( in line before that only comes one gigabyte switch and router that controlles internet, ip adresses..  - i didn't changed this two.. )

-One thing that I'm going to try today is to put cable from starting router to the pc. 
Also on computers are installed eset endpoint ( on scan it showed some threats but all cleaned)

I did all things that I found on google.. nothing helps....

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: share the dump files from C:\windows\minidump

Answer (score 0):

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL indicates that Microsoft Windows or a kernel-mode driver accessed paged memory at an invalid address while at a raised interrupt request level.

If a bad driver, you need to locate it.
A useful utility is
[BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html)
which analyzes the memory minidump amd points to the modules that were
on top of the stack when the crash occurred.

Comment: How its possible that on 5 computers shows same error? 
Windows update was off! 
I just don't get it..

Thank you for you answare, I will defintily try this.

Comment: First step is to analyze. Do all these problematic XPs have the same network card? Are there other XPs with the same card that do not have this problem?

Comment: More: Around the time that the problems started, was the firmware of the router updated?

Comment: I will check if they all have same network cards ( i'm not currently there, but 3 of them definelty have same network cards ), but i did put other network card in one PC, same problem persist.
Problem is in the morning hours, later it may occure but not that often..
Router have latest firmware ( its from 2015, no newer releses..)

Comment: On 3 machines is Intel PRO/100VE
On 2 machines Realtek PCie GBE Family Controller

From the software you recommended to me :

https://pastebin.com/bLSUf52P
https://pastebin.com/am5gTZHZ
https://pastebin.com/Zdhcmy8x

Comment: Which drivers are colored pink [like here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluescreenview.gif)?

Comment: ACPI.sys
ntsokernel.exe
Tclo.sys
TcRouter.sys

Comment: The first two are a part of Windows. The others seem to belong to the Beckhoff TwinCAT software system, whatever that is.

Comment: so how to fix it?

Comment: You need to find what to fix. Is that Beckhoff thing installed on all the computers? I have seen a case once where the problems were caused by a faulty network card that bombarded the network with bad packets. I don't know if that's your problem, but you should try to find out if the problem is on the network, maybe by isolating these computers on their own network. Then you will need to either call in the specialists or find out the cause by elimination.

Comment: The beckhoff think is installed on 3 , I have also problem on "naked" XP installation. 
Thank you for your time, and somekind of help. 
I will try to fix this..